# Split values table for extract with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, line, hashtable, extract

I would like to make a new line in my hashtable to extract it in a csv.

I initialize my variable in hastable

```
$vlr=@{}

$vlr["OS"]=,@("test","test2")
```

I extract my variable in a .csv

```
$Output += New-Object PSObject -Property $vlr

$output | Convert-OutputForCSV  | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Path $filepath
```

[and the problem is in the extraction the result of the values ​​is on the same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq5yf.png)

[My goal is that each value is in a different line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDUMF.png)

Comment: please, do not post images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What is `Convert-OutputForCSV` ?

Comment: General advice: [I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle/60708579?r=SearchResults&s=3|13.7702#60708579) as it is exponential expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-7) cmdlet for this:

```
$vlr=@{}
$vlr["OS"]=,@("test","test2") | Out-String
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property $vlr
$Object | ConvertTo-Csv
```

```
"OS"
"test
test2
"
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution does not work because in the case where $vlr with several names the extraction will be complicated

$vlr=@{}

$vlr["OS"]=,@("test","test2")

$vlr["PS"]=,@("lous","tique")

it's a problem

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-OutoutForCSV-6e552fc6
For the function Convert-OutputForCSV

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the posted function does, but you can make your own function to handle a single-key or multi-key hash table provided all of the key value counts are the same.

```
function Convert-OutputForCsv {
    param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [hashtable]$hash
    )

    # Array of custom object property names
    $keys = [array]$hash.Keys

    # Loop through each key's values
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $hash.($keys[0]).count; $i++) {
        # Custom object with keys as properties. Property values are empty.
        $obj = "" | Select $keys
        # Loop through key names
        for ($j = 0; $j -lt $keys.Count; $j++) {
            $obj.($keys[$j]) = $hash.($Keys[$j])[$i]
        }
        $obj
    }
}

$vlr=[ordered]@{}
$vlr["OS"]='test','test2'
$vlr["PS"]='lous','tique'
$vlr | Convert-OutputForCsv | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Path $filepath
```

---

Honestly, if you are in control of the input data, I would just type out a CSV instead of typing out hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

this solution is good in my simplified case but not adapted to my case unfortunately
I'm merging my old base2 array with my new base array and my goal is to concatenate the values ​​in an excel to make them usable

```
  $base2 = Get-content $filepath2 | select -first 1 
$base2 = $base2 -split ";" 
$base2 = $base2.Replace("`"", "") 
$cunt2 = $base2.count - 1  
$h2 = ipcsv $filepath2 -Delimiter ";" 
$HashTable2 = @{}
for ($i = 0 ; $i -le $cunt2 ; $i++) { 
    foreach ($r in $h2) { 
        $HashTable2[$base2[$i]] = $r.($base2[$i]) 
    }
```

[base2 = old tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1wc5.png)

```
  $base = Get-content $filepath2 | select -first 1 
$base = $base -split ";" 
$base = $base.Replace("`"", "") 
$cunt = $base.count - 1  
$h1 = ipcsv $filepath -Delimiter ";" 
$HashTable = @{}
for ($i = 0 ; $i -le $cunt ; $i++) { 
    foreach ($r in $h1) { 
        $HashTable[$base[$i]] = $r.($base[$i]) 
    }
```

[New tables $base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqGN5.png)

once the two arrays are initialized, I merge them and this is where I have to separate the values ​​row by row

```
$csvfinal = $hashtable, $hashtable2 | Merge-Hashtables
```